# SQL Job to extract data to For XML Path works fine on my machine, but not on customer Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd, for-xml-path, sql-job

I am working on a project for a customer where I have created a SQL View and a SQL Job to extract data from their DB for a third party vendor.   The data is to be exported as an XML document. The third party vendor has asked that the XML file not contain any plain text.

In testing, I have set this up on my local machine and it works fine.

On the customer server, I can query the view and it returns data. I can run a sql statement to query the view, and it returns data in the XML format desired. However, when the SQL job runs, the resulting data appears in an unusable string.

The SQL job runs as (CmdExex) and the text of the SQL Job is:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S <servername> -U <login name> -P <password> -d <databasename> 
-i <sql query /input location> -o <file output location and name>.xml 
-y 8000 -h -1
```

The job runs and queries the sql view by calling on this statement:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * FROM dbo.<ViewName>
FOR XML PATH ('INCIDENT');
```

The results should look like this:

```
<INCIDENT>
    <YearOf>18</YearOf>
    <IncdNo>xxx</Incdno>
```

And they do on my local machine when running this job.

However, on the customer site, the results look like this: (Truncated for space)

```
0x7575087590075E0075300759007575007550075E0057500757506590065006100720075F006600757506759006E0063006750075E006F0075750C7530061006C006C0057500790070006500753006F0067500650075750C7530061006C006C005750079007000
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? I've guessed SQL-Server and tagged it for you.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2014. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by editing this line

FOR XML PATH ('INCIDENT');

to add , TYPE at the end, as so

FOR XML PATH ('INCIDENT'), TYPE;